# Who maintains an API Gateway?

Tags: api, microservices

API Gateways are great.  They can produce a nice unified view of a sea of micro-services living behind them.  However, on large scale projects, what patterns can be adapted to allow a single API Gateway to sit over dozens or hundreds of micro-services?

**Example**

I have an endpoint on my gateway:  `https://mysite/api/books` which returns a list of books.  The payload of each book contains information for multiple micro-services, each of which is potentially owned by a different group of developers.

So when one of those teams needs to make a change to what a book *is*, how are those changes managed an coordinated?

E.g.

- The sales micro-service wants to include the price and perhaps discount
- The reviews micro-service wants to include a rating for the book

Or in other words **who is the custodian of an API gateway**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this depends entirely on your organization, team structure, environment, and management.

One option that CA put out was micro gateways which allow distributed management of APIs so dev teams can develop their own APIs and test them at a gateway level, but promotion to the "main" gateway was centrally managed by a dedicated team.

Centrally managed has pros and cons, but with that many micro services, a dedicated team to manage the APIs at the gateway separate from the different dev teams would be my recommendation.

Comment: And in the lack of a dedicated team this would fall to the operations/admin team, wouldn't it? Since the gateway for REST looks like just a reverse proxy, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy, it's not exactly the silver bullet I was hoping for, but (unfortunately for me!!) I believe you.  I've still not given up hope though.  If either of us (or anybody else reading this) comes across a more practical process/pattern for maintaining large API Gateways, please share!

Comment: Or is it just another piece of software? Because if it does translation and/or authentication it would need to be different for every product.

Comment: Hi Jan - that's an excellent point.  So you're saying that you should treat an API Gateway just like any other system.  I.e. Just because it has downstream systems, it doesn't mean that the teams of those downstream systems should get any say in its implementation.  Could you do me a favour an add that as an answer?  I think it's a good one.

Comment: I think that also depends on what sort of Gateway solution you're using. Setting up policies in a Spring Cloud Gateway vs. a CA API Gateway are done very, very differently. And if you're going to use a single Gateway, those policies have to be consistent, but the microservices behind the Gateway might be implemented in N number of ways. For example, if you're using Spring Cloud Gateway and have a Go microservice, the developer might not know how to write the Gateway policy. If not a dedicated team, it would still make sense to be a DEFINED team, even if that team has other responsibilities.